# Node JS application with Php Library

Tags: php, node.js, apache, payment-gateway, microservices

I have a web application which is written in Node JS, and now I came up to implement a payment gateway which doesn't support NodeJS. Although it supports PHP, Asp etc. I wanted to know if there is a way I can work this out. Is it possible to host Node and PHP application in the same server? Can we write microservice using RabbitMQ which will be a communication bridge between both NodeJS and PHP? Please suggest.

Comment: if you can do it with php you can do it with  js as well, what payment gateway are you talking about ?

Comment: Cybersecure Payment Gateway

Answer (score 1):

1. Most payment gateways support REST based APIs. So it doesn't matter what the underlying technology of your application is.
2. It is possible to host both PHP & Node.js applications in a single machine as long as they map to different ports.
3. Microservices often communicate with REST based APIs. So communication between the 2 applications above should be possible with or without a message broker like RabbitMQ. Whether you should have this mechanism in place for your scenario is debatable.

Comment: Yes, they do support REST, but place where I am living banks have implemented 3d Secure ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-D_Secure ). I have no idea if REST Api's can work if 3D Secure is in place.